# How to load external JS before component load in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I  have a custom date picker which do the following in a webpage. Now i included that file in component.ts like,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import '../../assets/js/transfor.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction-report',
  templateUrl: './transaction-report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transaction-report.component.css']
})
export class TransactionReportComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The date picker will do the following,

```
Copy
Export to excel
Export to PDF
Print
```

The code will look like this in transfor.js..

```
$(function () {
  $('#datepicker-autoclose').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
    });
  $('#datepicker-autoclose1').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
     });
   });

$(function () {
$('#example').DataTable( {
   "bPaginate": false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
    'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
 });
});
```

The import is not loading when page first load. It only working when page refresh, after first load.

Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: there is no angular js 2.

Comment: K.. Looking forward for possible ways to get it done.

Comment: are you using cli ?

Comment: Yeah!. I'm using Angular cli.